# How do I determine the output dimension of my input layer?

Tags: machine-learning, model, keras

I'm building a keras model for a binary classification.

```
model <- keras_model_sequential()
model %>%
    layer_dense(units=32,activation="relu",input_shape=10) %>%
    layer_dense(units=16,activation="relu") %>%
    layer_dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid')
```

Since my input matrix consists of `10` columns, I chose the value `10` for `input_shape`.
I also know that the number of hidden neurons should be between the size of the input and the output layer. However, I do not understand which value I should chose for the output dimension of my input layer (I set it to `32`).

Maybe someone of you is experienced :).
Thanks in advance!

Comment: it can be any number you want, and it's hard to tell what the best number is until you try it.

Answer (score 1):

In your Keras model, the input layer does not have an output dimension specified. The output dimension is automatically determined based on the number of units in the next layer, which in your case is the first hidden layer with 32 units.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Oh, that means that I have two input layers and that this would be the model with one input layer:
`model %>%
    layer_dense(units=16,activation="relu",input_shape=10) %>%
    layer_dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid')`